# I'm having trouble installing/using WordPress

Tags: wordpress, web-deployment

I want to make websites for people but I'm having some trouble installing WordPress. I already downloaded it's .zip files and unzipped them on a new folder on my desktop but unlike any other software I have downloaded, It doesn't have a .exe installing file. I'm basically a newbie in this coding world, but I love it so far. But anyway, I read part of the installation documentation and bumped into a little problem; in order to use WordPress to modify a website, you need a domain running under a host service company (that I can't currently afford). I'm not sure if I should install it locally to learn how to use it before I jump into the freelance industry. I really need to learn as quickly as possible because I want to land my first gigs as a web developer (and have a little chance with someone I know and don't want to lose the shot). I'd appreciate as most help as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are beginner, but that is not a problem, all of us was beginners!

So you first must to understand the logical things:

1. To have a website online on the internet you need to buy a domain (you can install WordPress locally, on a local-host).
2. The domain must be hosted on a hosting (you must to buy a hosting). Almost hosting have Linux as servers (so no .exe).
3. Almost any website (WordPress too) must be connected to a data-base (MySQL).
4. The nice way to manage data-base (create / edit / connect WordPress to database MySQL is via phpMyAdmin.

To install WordPress to a localhost (your computer) you must first to install a local server on your PC! **Read** this tutorial: https://www.themeum.com/install-wordpress-localhost/